# replacing sqlplus commands with mysql commands

Tags: mysql, sqlplus

i am trying to rewrite a script that is written in c-shell script to that uses sql plus command to get information from an oracle database but i am replacing it with mysql and i would like to replace all sqlplus syntax with mysql syntax. I am asking all the c-shell gurus to explain to me what this command means

```
 set SQLPLUS=${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus 

 set REPORT=${MYBD_HOME}/Scripts/report.sql
```

so somewhere along the line i invoke the sql plus command using the follwing

```
 ${SQLPLUS} ${MYDBUSER} @ &{REPORT}
```

i am able to say i undertand what the right hand values mean ({ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus) is the path to where my sqplus command is located and thus i need it to invoke the command and the {REPORT=$(MYBD_HOME}/Scripts.report.sql) is the path where my sql script that is to be ran by invoking the sqplus command resides correct?

what i dont understand is what the set command is initializing this to. is SQLPLUS a variable so i dont have to type the path when i try to put it in my .csh script?

If so then all i need to do to run this script on a mysql database is simply set the SQLPLUS(problably change it to MYSQL) to point to the path where my msql exec is right

```
  set MYSQL=${MYSQL_HOME}/bin/mysql
```

then just invoke mysql and run the sql statement

```
  ${MYSQL}${MYDBUSER}@${REPORT}
```

is this what i need to do ro tun the same .tsch script to get data from a mysql table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need something like this:

```
${MYSQL} -u $username -p$password -D $database < ${REPORT}
```

(The username and password are passed in differently to the mysql executable than they are passed to SQLPlus.  You'll need to parse out the username and the password from ${MYDBUSER}.  Likely, that contains a string such as "`scott/tiger`". The equivalent on the mysql command line client would be "`-u scott -ptiger -D scott`".

That @ (at sign) is a SQLPlus thing; it tells SQLPLus to read input from the specified filename. The equivalent in mysql would be the `source` command, e.g.

```
${MYSQL} -u $username -p$password <_EOD!
use $database 
source ${REPORT}
_EOD!
```

Also, your `report.sql` file likely includes `spool` and other SQLPLus specific commands. The mysql command line client is NOT ANYWHERE near as powerful a reporting tool as SQLPlus is.

---

**Addendum:**

**Q:** what exactly does the spool do?

The SQLPlus `spool` command directs output to a file. It's frequently used to create a log file from a SQLPLus session, and is also useful for creating report files.

```
set trimspool on
spool /tmp/file.lis
select 'foo' as foo from dual;
spool off
```

**Q:** Why can't i set the user name and passowrd to a variable and use that?

You could set a variable, the end result of the command line sent to the OS would be the same.

```
set MYDBUSER="-u username -ppassword -D database"
${MYSQL} ${MYDBUSER} <${REPORT}
```

**Q:**Seems like mysql is more verbose than sqlplus.

The mysql command line client takes unix-style options. These are equivalent:

```
mysql -u myusername -pmypassword -D mydatabase
mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --database=mydatabase
```

Comment: what exactly does the spool do?

Comment: why cant i set the user name and passowrd to a variable and use that. Seems like myql is more verbose than sqlplus

Comment: ok i shall try to do this. Seems like i just might as well rewrite the whole script. MYDBUSER is an environment variable i presume and it does not exist i am going to have to add both MYSQL_HOME and MYDBUSER to my env variables correct. This way i can execute the mysql commands in my script. I think i will also have to replace username and password with what i log into the mysql db?  lastly my report runs and sql statement and creates a .log file and puts it somewhere? I this what the spool command is doing? how do i do the same in mysql?  thanks

Comment: sorry MYDBUSER exist but it is set to raikin /raikin@mydb9i so i need to change this to -u raikin -p password -d database name? for mysql right?

Comment: @rambokyambo: yes. that's why i showed that in my original answer.  The "user/pass@tnsname" format is SQLPLus specific. NOTE: there is no space between the -p and the password for mysql: -pmypassword.

Comment: ok thank you. Is the syntax you gave me for spooling the correct syntax i need to add for mysql to create a report from the db? i apologize i am new to both scripting and sqplus and mysql

Comment: hey how do i perform the spool command in mysql. I have attempted to look up the same command in mysql and i have not been successfull